# Advice on how to pronounce properly 'en un', 'en un an', etc

Tags: prononciation

I know that for, e.g. 'en un an' the pronunciation is

ɑ̃n‿ɛ̃n‿ɑ̃

with the liaisons between the words and the nasal sounds, but I cannot figure out how to sound closer to a native.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first liaison (*en un*) is optional and rare, the second one (*un an*) always done, no exception.

*Un* can be realized as either /ɛ̃/, /œ̃/ or other variants, depending on the region.

The most common pronunciation around me (Paris area) is :

> En un an /**ɑ̃ ɛ̃n‿ɑ̃**/

but the alternative /**ɑ̃n‿ɛ̃n‿ɑ̃**/ is nevertheless valid.

Note also that the first liaison is expected, and even mandatory in fixed expressions, when the word following *un* starts with a consonant, so isn't itself subject to a liaison, e.g.:

> En un mot, merci !  /**ɑ̃n‿ɛ̃ mo**/